# Jquery plugin - How access var outside init function

Tags: jquery, plugins

Well, I've have already read several topics here and out as how access var outside the init function but as I'm new to javascript didn't figured out how to do it. I already thank you for your time.

I'm writting my first jquery plugin - a table that can sort, search text, hightlight rows... etc - and I'm facing one problem.

At the 'settings' block, there's an option i18N:{'x','y'} - while inside init method I can access it like 'options.i18N.search'. But in the method *get_table_body*, at the begining of jqxhr.complete(/* Insert options to manage table data */), I can't access by 'options.i18N.iSelected'. Ok I know is all about scope, but the only way I could solve to access it was making 'options = $.extend(settings, option)'- making it global.

So, I ask you: What's the other way I could access it in this code - without making 'options' global? I've tried $.yTable.options... and several other combination but with no success - that was expected as I didn't know what I was doing.

```
(function($){
var methods = {
    init : function( option ) { 
        /* Main settings */
        var settings = {
            tableClass:'yTable', /* the class of the table */
            dataFile: 'yTable.php', /* the file that fetch data in JSON format */
            dbTable:'yTableDB', /* the database name that holds the data */
            tColumns: [''], /* an array with the header titles of the table */
            dbTColumns: [''], /* an array with the table name in database */
            dbHColor: '#ded', /* Hover color of rows */
            dbCColor: '#ded', /* Color of column when sorting */
            tStrLen: 1, /* The minimum string length to search */
            insertBottonTh: false, /* Can insert header on bottom? */
            hasFunctions: false, /* Without extra functions */
            canDeleteRow : false, /* Cannot delete single row */
            canDeleteRows: false, /* Cannot delete rows */
            canSort: false, /* Cannot sort table columns */
            /* Options to translate returned text messages */
            i18N: {
                search : 'Buscar',
                confirm : 'Confirmar',
                confirmAll : 'Deseja realmente apagar os registros selecionados'
                        +'? Esta ação não poderá ser desfeita.',
                confirmDel : 'Por favor, confirme a remoção deste registro',
                iSelected : 'Com selecionados',
                noneSelected : 'Para utilizar esta função é necessário que selecione pelo menos um registro.',
                remove : 'Excluir'
            }
        };
        /* Simplify options name */
        var options = $.extend(settings, option);
        var tClass = options.tableClass;
        var tFile = options.dataFile;
        var tName = options.dbTable;
        var tColumns = options.tColumns;
        var dbColumns = options.dbTColumns;
        var tHoverColor = options.dbHColor;
        var tCColor = options.dbCColor;
        var tSLength = options.tStrLen;
        var tThBottom = options.insertBottonTh;
        var tFunctions = options.hasFunctions;
        var tcDeleteRow = options.canDeleteRow;
        var tcDelete = options.canDeleteRows; 
        var tcSort = options.canSort;
        var yTable='table.'+tClass;

        return this.each(function(){
            var obj = $(this);
            var n=tColumns.length;
            if($.isArray(tColumns)&&n>0){
                var th=false;
                var sort_img=false;
                if(tcSort)
                    sort_img='<div class="sort-img"></div>';
                else sort_img='';
                if(tFunctions&&tcDelete)
                    th+='<th width="18"><input type="checkbox" class="check_all" /></th>';
                /* Create the header */
                $.each(tColumns, function(k,v){
                    th+='<th title="'+dbColumns[k]+'" class="th'+k+'">'+v+sort_img+'</th>';
                });
            }
            /* Append table to object */
            var table='<div id="yTableSearch">'+options.i18N.search+': <input type="text" class="yTSearch" /></div>'
            +'<div style="clear:both;"></div><div class="yTableFunctions"></div>'
            +'<table class="'+tClass+'"></table>';
            obj.append(table);
            /* Append delete single row if requested */
            if(tcDeleteRow)
                th+='<th></th>';
            /* Append the headers to table */
            $(yTable).append('<thead>'+th+'</thead>');
            /* If bottom is requested, insert it - its content is the same of thead */
            if(tThBottom)
                $(yTable).append('<tfoot>'+th+'</tfoot>');
            /* Load the body of the table(tbody) */
            methods.get_table_body(tClass, tFile, tName,dbColumns,
                tFunctions, tcDeleteRow, tHoverColor, tCColor, tSLength, tThBottom, tcDelete, yTable);
        });
    },
    get_table_body: function(tClass, tFile, tName, dbColumns,
        tFunctions, tcDeleteRow, tHoverColor, tCColor, tSLength, tThBottom,
        tcDelete, yTable, tCol, qStr){
        $(yTable+' input.check_all').prop('checked',false);
        /* Parameters to receive(order) */
        /* tClass, tFile, tName, dbColumns, tFunctions, tcDeleteRow,tHoverColor,
         * tThBottom, tCColor, tSLength, tcDelete, yTable[, tCol][, qStr] */
        /*****************************************/
        if(!tCol) tCol=':';
        var Cols = tCol.split(':');
        var rCol = $.trim(Cols[0]);
        var sCol = $.trim(Cols[1]);
        var colName = $.inArray(sCol, dbColumns);
        var qCol='';
        var sType='';
        var qByName='';
        var asort=Array(2);
        if(typeof(sCol)=='string' && colName>=0){
            var hObj = $(yTable+' thead th[title='+sCol+']')
            .prop('class');
            var tc=hObj
            .match(/th{1}[^a-z]/);
            var cObj = $(yTable+' th.'+tc);
            var sortImg = $(yTable+' th.'+tc+' div.sort-img');
            var order = hObj.match(/ASC|DESC/);
            if(cObj.hasClass('DESC')&&rCol=='sstring'){
                cObj.removeClass('DESC').addClass('ASC');
                sortImg.css('background-position', '-32px 0');
                asort=[sCol, 'ASC'];
            } else if(cObj.hasClass('ASC')&&rCol=='sstring'){
                cObj.removeClass('ASC').addClass('DESC');
                sortImg.css('background-position', '-48px 0');
                asort=[sCol, 'DESC'];
            } else if(rCol=='qstring'&&order!=null){
                asort=[sCol, $.trim(order)];
            } else {
                $(yTable+' th').removeClass('ASC').removeClass('DESC');
                $(yTable+' th div.sort-img').css('background-position', '0 0');
                cObj.addClass('ASC');
                sortImg.css('background-position', '-32px 0');
                asort=[sCol, 'ASC'];
            }
        }
        if($.isArray(asort)){
            var qCol = asort[0];
            var sType = asort[1];
        }
        if(qStr){
            if(qStr.length>=tSLength && typeof(sCol)=='string'){
                qByName = qStr;
            }
        }

        /*****************************************/
        /* Get data in JSON format */
        var jqxhr = $.get(tFile, {
            'table':tName,
            'cname': dbColumns.join(','),
            'column' : qCol,
            'sort' : sType,
            'sname' : qByName,
            'slength' : tSLength
        },
        function(){
            /* Remove tbody to append a new one */
            $('table.'+tClass+' tbody').remove();
        }).success(function(data){
            /* Mount tbody content */
            if(data!='norow'){
                var rows = $.parseJSON(data);
                var i=0;
                var tbody=false;
                tbody+='<tbody>';
                var tr = false;                
                $.each(rows,function(){
                    var objf = rows['tr'+i];
                    tr+='<tr id="tr'+i+'">'
                    if(tFunctions&&tcDelete)
                        tr+='<td><input type="checkbox" name="tr'+i+'" class="check" /></td>';
                    $.each(objf, function(v){
                        if(v!=='id'){
                            tr+='<td>'+objf[v]+'</td>';
                        }
                    });
                    if(tcDeleteRow)
                        tr+='<td><div class="delete_row" id="r'+objf['id']+'"></div></td>';
                    tr+='</tr>';
                    i++;
                });
            } else {
                var ncolumns = dbColumns.length;
                if(tFunctions&&tcDelete) {
                    ncolumns++;
                }
                if(tcDeleteRow)
                    ncolumns++;
                tr = '<tr><td colspan="'+ncolumns+'">...</td></tr>';
            }
            tbody+=tr+'</tbody>';
            $(yTable).append(tbody);
        }).error(function(){
            alert('Fail');
        });
        jqxhr.complete(function(){
            /* Permit select/deselect all inputs */
            $(yTable+' input.check_all').click(function(){
                var val = this.checked;
                $('.check_all').prop('checked',this.checked);
                var input = $(yTable+' tbody input[type=checkbox]');
                input.prop('checked', val);
                if(input.prop('checked')==true)
                    input.closest('tr').addClass('ySelected');
                else input.closest('tr').removeClass('ySelected');
            });
            /* Insert options to manage table data */
            if(tFunctions&&tcDelete){
                if($('div.yTableFunctions').children().length==0){
                    $('div.yTableFunctions').append(options.i18N.iSelected+': <select class="yTableOperations">'
                        +'<option class="none"> -- </option></select>'
                        +' <input type="button" value="'+options.i18N.confirm+'" name="bConfirm" />');
                    $('div.yTableFunctions').clone().insertAfter(yTable);
                }
                /* If can delete by selection */
                if(tFunctions&&tcDelete){
                    if($('div.yTableFunctions select.yTableOperations option.delete').length==0){
                        methods.delete_selected(yTable);
                    }
                }                    
            }
            /* If requested to delete single row */
            if(tcDeleteRow){
                methods.delete_single_row(tClass);
            }
            /* Stripe table rows */
            methods.stripe_table(tClass);
            /* Select row on click */
            methods.select_on_click(tClass);
            /* First verify what column will be hightlighted ... */
            var i=parseInt($(yTable+' thead th[title='+sCol+']').index(),10)+1;
            /* ... now highlight coresponding column */
            $(yTable+' tr td:nth-child('+i+')').css({
                'background-color': tCColor
            });
            /* ... now sort table */
            methods.sort_table($(yTable+' div.sort-img'),yTable,tClass,
                tFile, tName,dbColumns, tFunctions, tcDeleteRow, tHoverColor, tCColor, tSLength, tThBottom, tcDelete);
            /* Highlight on mouse over */
            methods.highlight_on_hover(tClass, tHoverColor,tCColor);
            methods.search_string(tClass, tFile, tName, dbColumns, tFunctions, tcDeleteRow,
                tHoverColor, tCColor, tSLength, tThBottom, tcDelete, yTable);
        });
    },
    stripe_table: function(c){
        $('table.'+c+' tbody tr').removeClass('stripes');
        $('table.'+c+' tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripes');
    },
    highlight_over_highlighted_cell: function(trId,c,h){
        $('table.'+c+' thead th').each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('ASC')||$(this).hasClass('DESC'))
                var thId = true;
            if(thId){
                var tHClass=$(this).prop('class').match(/th{1}[^a-z]/);
                /* First verify what column will be hightlighted ... */
                var i=parseInt($('table.'+c+' thead th.'+tHClass).index(),10)+1;
                /* ... now highlight coresponding cell */
                $('table.'+c+' tr#'+trId+' td:nth-child('+i+')').css({
                    'background-color': h
                });
            }
        });
    },
    highlight_on_hover: function(c,h,rh){
        var thisTr = $('table.'+c+' tbody tr');
        thisTr.mouseover(function(){
            /* Tr id */
            var thisTrId=$(this).prop('id');
            $(this).css({
                'background-color':h
            });
            methods.highlight_over_highlighted_cell(thisTrId,c,h);
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).css('background-color','');
            /* Tr id */
            var thisTrId=$(this).prop('id');
            methods.highlight_over_highlighted_cell(thisTrId,c,rh);
        });
    },
    select_on_click:function(c){
        $('table.'+c+' tbody tr').click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var input = $this.children('td').children('input');
            /* Select/desselect row input */
            input.prop('checked', input.prop('checked')?false:true);
            /* Toggle highlight*/
            if(input.prop('checked')==true)
                $this.addClass('ySelected');
            else $this.removeClass('ySelected');
        });
    },
    delete_single_row : function(c){
        $('div.delete_row').click(function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight_row');
            //                var rId = this.id.replace(/r/,'');
            if(confirm(options.i18N.confirmDel)){
                //                    $.get('delete_row.php',{
                //                        id:rId
                //                    },
                //                    function(data){
                //                        alert(c);
                //                    });
                $(this).closest('tr').hide();
            }else{
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('highlight_row');
            }
        });
    },
    delete_selected: function(c){
        var oper = $('select.yTableOperations');
        oper.append('<option class="delete" value="delete">'+options.i18N.remove+'</option>');
        oper.change(function(){
            var opt = $(this).val();
            oper.each(function(){
                $(this).prop('value',opt); 
            });
        });
        $('.yTableFunctions input[type=button]').click(function(){
            if(this.value === options.i18N.confirm && oper.val()==='delete'){
                var regs=[];
                var i=0;
                $(c+' input[type=checkbox].check')
                .each(function(){
                    if(this.checked){
                        regs[i] = this.name;
                        $('tr#'+regs[i]).addClass('highlight_row');/* Highlight marked rows */
                        i++;
                    }
                });
                if(regs.length>0){
                    var rows=[];
                    if(confirm(
                        options.i18N.confirmAll
                        )){
                        $.each(regs, function(k,v){/* Loop through each row */
                            rows[k]='"'+k+'":"'+v+'"';
                            $('tr#'+v).addClass('highlight_del')/* Highlight to delete */
                            .hide('slow') /* Give some time to hide */
                            .remove();/* Remove row */
                        });
                        rows = '{'+rows.join()+'}'; 
                        $(c+' input[type=checkbox].check_all')
                        .prop('checked',false);
                    } else {
                        $('tr').removeClass('highlight_row');
                    }
                }else{
                    alert(options.i18N.noneSelected);
                }
            }
        });            
    },
    sort_table : function(ce,yTable, tClass, tFile, tName,dbColumns,
        tFunctions, tcDeleteRow, tHoverColor, tCColor, tSLength, tThBottom, tcDelete){
        $(ce).unbind('click').click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            var tCol='sstring:'+$(this).closest('th').prop('title');
            var qStr=$('#yTableSearch input.yTSearch').val();
            /* Get data sorted */
            methods.get_table_body(tClass, tFile, tName,dbColumns, tFunctions,
                tcDeleteRow, tHoverColor, tCColor, tSLength, tThBottom, tcDelete, yTable, tCol, qStr);
        });
    },
    search_string : function(tClass, tFile, tName,dbColumns, tFunctions, tcDeleteRow,
        tHoverColor, tCColor, tSLength, tThBottom, tcDelete, yTable){
        $('#statistics').unbind('keyup').on('keyup', '#yTableSearch input.yTSearch',
            function(e){
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                var qStr=null;
                if(this.value.length>=tSLength
                    &&((e.keyCode>46&&e.keyCode<91)
                        ||(e.keyCode>95&&e.keyCode<106))
                    ||e.keyCode==8||e.keyCode==46
                    ){
                    qStr = this.value;
                    var noSort = 'qstring:';
                    $(yTable+' thead tr th').each(function(e){
                        if($(this).hasClass('ASC')|| $(this).hasClass('DESC')){
                            noSort += $(this).prop('title');
                        }
                    })
                    methods.get_table_body(tClass, tFile, tName,dbColumns, tFunctions,
                        tcDeleteRow, tHoverColor, tCColor, tSLength, tThBottom, tcDelete, yTable, noSort, qStr);
                }                        
            });
    }
};
$.fn.yTable=function(method){
    /* Method calling logic */
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Desculpe-me, mas o método "' +  method + '" não existe no plugin yTable!' );
    }    
};
})(jQuery);
```

It worked! Thank you for your time in helping me with this problem. I'll will put the solution below, as others can have the same problem. Following @Beetroot-Beetroot directives, I've undestood better this issue.

The modifications was little... see them below

Method Init:

First I withdrawn the i18N block from settings and put it inside return this.each()

```
    init : function( options ) { 
  // codes ...
return this.each(function(){
            var obj = $(this);
            var data = obj.data('yTable');
            data ={
                /* Options to translate returned text messages */
                i18N: {
                    target : obj,
                    search : 'Buscar',
                    confirm : 'Confirmar',
                    confirmAll : 'Deseja realmente apagar os registros selecionados'
                    +'? Esta ação não poderá ser desfeita.',
                    confirmDel : 'Por favor, confirme a remoção deste registro',
                    iSelected : 'Com selecionados',
                    noneSelected : 'Para utilizar esta função é necessário que selecione pelo menos um registro.',
                    remove : 'Excluir',
                    showReg : 'Mostar ',
                    showRegEnd : ' por página',
                    failDbQuery : 'Erro! Não foi possível buscar dados na base de dados. Por favor, verifique sua configuração.'
                }

            }
            obj.data('yTable', data);
```

//                var options = $.extend(data,options);
                var yOptionLang = obj.data('yTable');

Now I can access i18N inside **init** by *yOptionLang.i18N.showReg*. As I need to pass i18N to the method **get_table_body**, I do it by doing *methods.get_table_body(tClass...yTable).apply(this)*.

As I call other methods from **get_table_body**, I rewrite it like...

```
get_table_body:function(tClass,...nReg){
        return $.each(function(){
            var yOption = $(this).data('yTable');
            // code here ...
```

And I can access i18N by doing *yOption.i18N.iSelected*... now, inside this method I have to pass i18N to other methods, so I do it by...

```
/* If requested to delete single row */
                if(tcDeleteRow){
                    methods.delete_single_row(tClass).apply(yOption);
                }
```

...in this case, the method **delete_single_row** will begin with...

```
delete_selected:function(c){
        return $.each(function(){
            var yOption = this;
            // code here...
```

... and I can access i18N by *yOption.i18N.remove*

Other tricky thing, is that I need to call **get_table_body** from other methods, so I have to put **.apply(this)** in those methods, like the below to sort the table.

```
sort_table:function(ce,yTable, tClass, tFile, tName,dbColumns,
        tFunctions, tcDeleteRow, tHoverColor, tCColor, tSLength, tThBottom, tcDelete){
        $(ce).unbind('click').click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            var tCol='sstring:'+$(this).closest('th').prop('title');
            var qStr=$('#yTableSearch input.yTSearch').val();
            var nReg = $('div#yTableRegs select#yTableRegSelect').prop('value');
            /* Get data sorted */
            methods.get_table_body(tClass, tFile, tName,dbColumns, tFunctions,
                tcDeleteRow, tHoverColor, tCColor, tSLength, tThBottom, tcDelete, yTable, tCol, qStr, nReg).apply(this);
        });
    }
```

Well, with this modifications now I can pass variables from methods to methods - thank you for your help!

Comment: Should `settings` be something that is changeable from outside, or read-only?

Comment: yes the settings will be changeable from outside. Following @Beetroot-Beetroot directives, now I can pass variables from method to method without making them globals - that was I wanted. Thank you for your time.

Comment: From what you say, I expect that `get_table_body()` is an internal utility function that doesn't need to be called as a method of the plugin. If so, then it (and any other utility functions) can be defined with `var get_table_body = function(){...};` inside the plugin but outside the `methods` object. Depending on how they are written, utilities can be called with `.call(...)`, `.apply(...)` or with a normal function call.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

This pattern is seriously clever but rather difficult to penetrate.

The main things to understand are :

- that any vars declared in the outermost scope (before `var methods = ...`) will be specific (and private) to the plugin itself, not to any particular invocation of it
- that any vars declared in any method will be specific (and private) to each particular invocation of that method and not directly available to any other method. The init method is no different from any other method in this respect.

Consequently, there is no apparent way to share vars between methods.

### DOM to the rescue

Fortunately, jQuery makes it simple to store data in the DOM and that's exactly what's necessary here.

Here's a template for init, based on the tutorial **[here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)**:

```
init : function(options) {
    return this.each(function(index){
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data(pluginName);
        // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
        if (!data) {
            var settings = {
                //default settings here
            };
            if(options) { $.extend(settings, options); }
            data = {
                target : $this,
                //other data properties here
            }
            $this.data(pluginName, data);
            //do other init stuff here
            //create further data properties as required
        }
    });
},
```

Thus, data established in init is available to other methods :

```
myMethod : function() {
    return this.each(function(index){
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data(pluginName);
        //do other method stuff here
        //access data properties as required
    });
},
```

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation - it helped me to undestand better this question. The modifications I've done was little inside the methods(I only put 'var data = $this.data(pluginName)',data={},and $this.data(pluginName,data)  'return this.each' didn't work - but 'return $.each' did the job. As I only call the method 'get_table_body' from init, I had to put '.apply(this)' after it. As I call other methods from 'get_table_body', I put '.apply(Option)' <- referencing the object-- in these methods in order to pass the variable to other methods, but now it works fine.